# Task asynchronous programming run synchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

by reading the following guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ I was trying to create three tasks that should run async, concurrently, but they actually run synchrously. I'm wondering where I'm wrong

```
Task<double?[]> rainfallGridValuesTask = Rainfall.ValuesAsync(rainfallGridValuesRepo.GetAll());  //it takes 5s
Task<double?[]> rainfallAvgValuesTask = Rainfall.AveragesAsync(rainfallAvgGridValuesRepo.GetAll());  //it takes 5s
Task<double?[][]> rainfallAnomaliesTask = Rainfall.AnomaliesAsync(rainfallGridValuesRepo.GetAll());  //it takes 5s
```

where the methods are like the following:

```
public static async Task<double?[]> Values(IQueryable<RainfallGridValue> rainfallGridValues)
{
    double?[] outputValues = new double?[108];

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);  //Simulate the time taken by the method
    return outputValues;
}
```

Then I try to get the value returned by the task in this way:

```
rainfallValueChart.Data = await rainfallGridValuesTask;
rainfallAverageChart.Data = await rainfallAvgValuesTask ;
rainfallAnomalyChart.Data = await rainfallAnomaliesTask ;
```

But when I run this code, it waits for 5s on each of the three Async methods, so what's wrong and how can I run them concurrently and proceed when all tasks have been completed?

Comment: Async methods are only async from the first call of "await". Replace `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);` with `await Task.Delay(5000);`

Comment: Async is all about using a single thread more efficiently. It is *not* about concurrency and multi threaded applications.

Comment: Are these supposed to be performing 5 seconds of CPU-intensive computation?  Then your simulation is pretty good and the observations are valid.  Are they supposed to be performing 5 seconds of I/O?  Then you should switch to `await Task.Delay` for your simulation.

Comment: @BenVoigt it's more related to I/O as they need to query a Remote DB with complex queries. So the implementation is correct, it's the way I'm simulating that is wrong? and the comment of TJRockefeller?

Comment: @Giox: As long as the actual methods are using `await` internally, you should simulate with `await Task.Delay()`.  If they aren't using `await` internally, but some other async/overlapped system, like BeginXYZ/EndXYZ or callbacks, you can make a wrapper that's compatible with awaitable Tasks.

Comment: @BenVoigt let's simplify it saying that it's only a query on linq, how could I wrap it?

Comment: @Giox: If it's an SQL query (SELECT command), you would use `ExecuteReaderAsync` instead of `ExecuteReader`.  LINQ can be used for all kinds of different backends, so your situation may vary.

Comment: Also, please don't ignore compiler warnings. There is a compiler warning that literally says `Values` will run synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, instead of `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)`, use `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));`. This would simulate doing five seconds of I/O (not five seconds of CPU computation) in each of the waiting tasks.